# JQuery Draggable: Is it possible to snap to grid after mouse release?

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

Basically, i want to use the grid option to snap a draggable div toa  30 x 30 grid but i want to keep the dragging smooth. So is there a way i can snap to the grid on mouse release (or something similar)

Answer (score 5):

correction to @Zed
this will use the center for deciding which grid to place it in. which ever most of the draggable is in is the one it goes.

```
stop: function(e, ui) {
    var grid_x = 30;
    var grid_y = 30;
    var elem = $( this );
    var left = parseInt(elem.css('left'));
    var top = parseInt(elem.css('top'));
    var cx = (left % grid_x);
    var cy = (top % grid_y);

    var new_left = (Math.abs(cx)+0.5*grid_x >= grid_x) ? (left - cx + (left/Math.abs(left))*grid_x) : (left - cx);
    var new_top = (Math.abs(cy)+0.5*grid_y >= grid_y) ? (top - cy + (top/Math.abs(top))*grid_y) : (top - cy);

    ui.helper.stop(true).animate({
        left: new_left,
        top: new_top,
        opacity: 1,
    }, 200);
},
```

Answer (score 3):

If that is all you want to do with the grid, you could emulate it:

```
$("#myobj").draggable({
  ...
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    t = parseInt($(this).css(top);
    l = parseInt($(this).css(left);
    $(this).css(top , t - t % 30);
    $(this).css(left, l - l % 30);
  }
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Try transition!**

A nice little something I just discovered now is, that if you give the dragged element the css property of transition it will have an effect on the speed it snaps to grid.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    containment: 'window',
    grid: [30, 30]
  });
});
```

```css
.draggable {
  background: #333;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: 'sans-serif', 'arial';
  padding: 5px 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: top 0.05s ease-in-out, left 0.05s ease-in-out
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="draggable">Drag Me!</div>
```